# Load JSON into UItableView in Swift

Tags: ios, json, uitableview, swift

I've been trying to return string urls from JSON and store it in array and then show the array in `UITableView`. but it shows empty `UILabel`.

```
class PhotosTableViewController: UITableViewController {


let imageLoadURL = "https://..."
    var TAG_IMG_URL = []


    verride func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

                getLatestPhotos()

        }

     override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            return 1
        }

        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return TAG_IMG_URL.count
        }

        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! KivaLoanTableViewCell
              cell.nameLabel.text = TAG_IMG_URL[indexPath.row] as? String
            return cell
        }

        func getLatestPhotos() {
                let request = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: imageLoadURL)!)
                let urlSession = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
                let task = urlSession.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in


                    if error != nil {
                        println(error.localizedDescription)
                    }

                    self.TAG_IMG_URL = self.parseJsonData(data)
                    println("\(self.TAG_IMG_URL.count)")

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    })

                })

                task.resume()
            }


            func parseJsonData(data: NSData) -> NSArray {

                    var error:NSError?

                    let jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error) as? NSDictionary

                    if error != nil {
                        println(error?.localizedDescription)
                    }

                    if let j = jsonResult, let mediaObjects = j.valueForKeyPath("feed.entry.media$group.media$content") as? NSArray {

                        if let imageUrls: AnyObject = mediaObjects.valueForKey("url") {
                           TAG_IMG_URL = imageUrls as! NSArray
                        }
                    }
                    println("\(TAG_IMG_URL)")


                    self.alert.dismissWithClickedButtonIndex(0, animated: true)

                    return TAG_IMG_URL

                }

}
```

During `parseJsonData` it returns the urls which it look like (below), but when i try to show it in the `UITableView` it always becomes empty `UILabel` so what am i doing wrong here ?:

```
(
        (
        "https://..."
    ),
        (
        "https://..."
    )
)
```

**Note** : in `numberOfRowsInSection` it returns the right amount which its 2 urls.

Comment: maybe `cell.nameLabel.text = TAG_IMG_URL[indexPath.row] as? NSString`

Comment: it says "cannot assign value of type NSString? to value of type String?"

Comment: try printing to console `TAG_IMG_URL[indexPath.row]` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`method

Comment: it prints `(
    "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-uubi7qNJ2Kw/VIbLAn8TlJI/AAAAAAAAAOM/gsv76rQICtQ/IMG_20140523_170813.jpg"
)
(
    "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-q-vWgMdlEfU/VIbLHRMWikI/AAAAAAAAAOM/u4QP7_o68E8/IMG_20140628_152242.jpg"
)` how its possible to get the strings only from this array !

Comment: then maybe your problem is in your storyboard file, have you set the correct cell identifier and cell class?

Comment: Yes for sure cell identifier is Cell. by the way I've added a dummy label. i can see in the `UITableView` 2 cells which is the count of the TAG_IMG_URL array . but it doesn't print the array into the url labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! KivaLoanTableViewCell
              cell.nameLabel.text = TAG_IMG_URL[indexPath.row][0] as? String
            return cell
        }
```

The problem that you have 2-dimensional array, so you should get first object in object:
`TAG_IMG_URL[indexPath.row].firstObject` or `TAG_IMG_URL[indexPath.row][0]`.